# Vertical align issue inside a div with float element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical align middle for my `input` and a tag element inside a div.

I have

```
<div id='title-container'>
        <div id='logo'><img src='images/topLogo.png'></div>
       <div id='search'><input type='text'><a id='btn' href='#'>test button</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to display something like

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|    ----------------------------------                             
|    |            topologic.png       |               my input box    test button                         
|    ----------------------------------                        
|________________________________________________________________________________
```

CSS

```
#title-container{ 
   height: 80px;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo{
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 10px;
}
#search{
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I want to vertical align my input box and test button inside my title-container div and float these two items to the right.

The above code will get me

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|    ----------------------------------                             
|    |            topologic.png        |my input box    test button                         
|    ----------------------------------                        
|_________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am not sure how to float my `input` box and `test` button to the right. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 #title-container{ 
    height: 80px;
   width: 980px;
   background-color: yellow;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }

 #logo{
   display: table-cell;
   margin: 10px;
 float:left;
 }
 #search{
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: right;
   margin: 10px;
   vertical-align: middle;
 float:right;
 }
```

Comment: this won't vertical align the #search div +1 though.

Comment: in opera everithing's ok. Although, removing `display: table-cell` from `#logo` & `#search` selectors should improve result

Answer (score 0):

These tags do wonders:

```
display: inline-block;
float: left;
float: right;
```

I think this jfiddle is what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/LeBsN/1/